# Can you use a binary DLL for your own App?

Tags: c#, windows, dll, components

Is it possible to copy a DLL from an installed application into your own bin folder, link to it and call functions at runtime, if you know the API? Does the DLL change if you've bought it from the component vendor and if you grab it off an install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.  Check the license agreement to make sure you are allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If the license is something that allows this, yes. e.g. GPL, LGPL, BSD, MIT, or a whole lot of other open-source licenses. Some commercial licenses may allow you to redistribute stuff in binary form for your own programs, but AFAIK that's pretty rare unless you pay a lot of money.

EDIT: If it's GPL or LGPL you either have to provide the source code (for the DLL) or provide some way for the user to get it.

Comment: Who's asking you about legalities? All I wanted to know is if it was possible.

Comment: Well, depending on legalities, it might be impossible ;-)